# Environment specific services config in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I need to access some private services via the container while in the `dev` environment.

I thought it would be simple - I'd just make them public specifically for `dev` like so:

**app/config/services.yml:**

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    MyBundle\:
        resource: '../../*'
        exclude: '../../{Entity,Repository,DoctrineMigrations,DependencyInjection,Tests,Util}'
```

**app/config/services_dev.yml:**

```
imports:
- { resource: services.yml }

services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: true
```

**app/config/config_dev.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: services_dev.yml }
```

This however does not yield the desired result: services behave as if private, config is not merged at all(e.g. when you have parameter injection, sy yells that I must define them explicitly, even if the parent config already does).

There's plenty of examples, in the default config of Sy, where specific parameters get overridden for various environments, but for some reason this does not seem to be the case for services. Is the services config processed in a special way somehow? Have I misunderstood something? What's going on here?

P.S. I know about dependency injection, I know accessing the container is considered bad practice, that's not the point of the question. Please do not suggest that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work, because your defaults only work on the services defined in your `services_dev.yaml`. That does not include the imports.

You could try a `services_dev.yaml` like this:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    MyBundle\Services\MyPublicService: ~
```

This will overwrite the service and make it public. Obviously you have to replace the class with the actual service.

You do not need to import the other services. The kernel will take care of loading this class.

Comment: That seems to be true. However the only confirmation in documents I've been able to find was an off-hand code comment in the doc where these changes are introduced. Is there like a citation you can point to? In any case, since defaults only apply to this file, I tried the bulk import option, like in services.yml, but that overwrites all services from the import, meaning if you have ones that require additional config(say parameter binding), you need to redefine them and at this point you might as well copy the entire file. But what you suggested is a good solution for individual services.

Comment: You can overwrite already defined services the way I showed above. It might be that this does not work for multiple services, so something like `MyBundle\: ~` might not work like this. I have to search for a citation that explains it, but at least when starting a new project in the symfony 4-style setup it will tell you in a comment in the services.yaml: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/3.3/config/services.yaml#L9

Comment: I have to take a look at an example project and play around to see if overwriting only the public option is doable like this. The only other possible solution I have is, creating a CompilerPass that you only enable in dev/prod that will overwrite all defined services (from a namespace) and set them `public: true`, but that might be overkill

Comment: Yea, that's the code comment I was referring to. It's just too easily missable. I also stumbled on the compiler pass approach in the context of testing - where, for tests you want your private services available. The problem here is essentially the same - different visibility for services depending on environment. It might actually not be that much of an overkill and a good general solution. Ironically, your approach here is probably better for testing, as it explicitly lists the tested services, which seems a good idea.